# Fetch all the record from a column of a table and export into other column of a table in CSV form in sql server .net

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've to create Sproc for below requirement....

I've got two table:

TableA Contains: ID (identity column primary key)

TableB contains: RandomID (This column will store ID that will be generated after randomly sorting Table A "ID" using NEWID() )

Now, my requirement is After random sorting of all "ID" from "TableA" that Id must be stored in the column "RandomID" of TableB
It means :
If I'm generating the Random No. i.e

```
"select ID from TableA order by NewID()"
```

Output of above query as:

3
2
4
5
2
.
.
.
19

*then, how to export the above output into other column i.e "RandomID"  of TableB in CSV form ?? i.e 
"RandomID column of TableB" must store in the form of

3,2,4,5....,19

I've to use cursor for this requirement but how to export it to other table after declaring CURSOR and to use according to my requirement, or is their any other alternative to achieve this goal because of Cursor performance issue ??

Please, enlighten me soon.

Thanks In advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by using Cursor ultimately,

```
 declare @ids varchar(50),@qNameIdCSV varchar(max)=''
 declare RandomCursor cursor for select ID from TableA order by NEWID()
        open RandomCursor 
        fetch next from RandomCursor into @ids
        while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        begin
        --print @ids
        set @qNameIdCSV=@qNameIdCSV+','+@ids
        fetch next from RandomCursor into @ids
        end
        close RandomCursor 
        deallocate RandomCursor 
        set @qNameIdCSV=SUBSTRING(@qNameIdCSV,2,len(@qNameIdCSV)-1) 

print @qNameIdCSV --check the required output
or 
insert into tableA (RandomID) values (@qNameIdCSV) -- this will save the random generated ID using NEWID() into the required column in CSV form
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert the select resulting in multiple rows into a single column of CSV then this might work:

```sql
DECLARE @CSVSTRING VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CSVSTRING = ''
SELECT @CSVSTRING = @CSVSTRING + ID + ',' FROM TableA ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT SUBSTRING(@CSVSTRING, 0, LEN(@CSVSTRING))
```

No cursor needed...

And also another way of interpreting your question could be that you want to `insert` a row per result from that query into `TableB` then you want the following:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (RandomID)
SELECT ID FROM TableA ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: from your above query I'm getting the random Id generated but for that I've to use looping till n-th ID because after certain interval the same id is getting repeated.But,what i need to do is, once that Id is generated it must not get repeated and unique ID must be stored into TableB column RandomID.

Comment: Also, for no repetition i've to use loop to check the existing value (which may be n times also) and then i should insert into other column of tableB...